# Java Swing JPanel. How do I paint shapes?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have implemented a class `DrawingPane extends JPanel` to draw some shapes. I have created inside an individual method for each type of shape, for example to circles corresponds :

```
public void paintCircles(Graphics g) {
           super.paint(g);
```

However I am not able to invoke this from another class through a reference to class `DrawingPane`. How can this be done? If it is not possible this way, how can I invoke an individual method to draw each type of shape, since the code requirements are different with different shapes?

Moreover, the method scrollRectToVisible from class `JPanel` does not apply to objects `RoundRectangle2D.Double`. How can make these shapes also visible?

Comment: Do the [Performing Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) tutorial.  If you cannot figure it out from that, I suggest you prepare and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `paintComponent(Graphics g)` in your `DrawingPane` and you can use `draw(Shape s)` to draw any shape:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;    
        g2.draw(yourShape);
}
```

Comment: Ok, as you describe it, I still need to check with an if-else-if inside the paintComponent which method is to be invoked, since I have to insert into the paintComponent the whole of methods applying to each shape individually like paintCircle, paintRectangles etc. Could I invoke the appropriate one (for example paintCircle)  without if-else-if from outside of the class, namely from a class ScrollPane?

Comment: @arjacsoh: No, I have updated my answer, you can use `draw(Shape s)` to draw any shape, e.g. line, rectangle, circle or what you want.

Comment: @arjacsoh with or without logic, you _never_ call paintXX from any class outside ... that's not how Swing painting works, please read the tutorial, Andrew already suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your `Graphics` to `Graphics2D` and use `public void draw(Shape s)` method passing all the `Shape`s you have. For any `Shape` you can use `public Rectangle getBounds()` and pass the `Rectangle` to the scrollRectToVisible.